# Display hidden DIVS inline during Transit.js transformations?

Tags: jquery, html, css, transformation, fullpage.js

New here; hope I get this right!

I'm using transit.js to swap DIVs within a fullpage.js slide. Initially, all DIVs but the "intro" text are hidden via a .hide CSS class. There are three buttons below the "slidetext" area that, when clicked, show content related to the button. For each click, the JS checks to see if the content for that button is already displayed; if it is, nothing happens. If it isn't, all other possible visible divs are transformed offscreen and hidden, and the requested DIV is loaded up to the right of the screen, slides into view, and becomes visible (with a little opacity transition).

My problem is that the showing and hiding of divs during the transformations is causing the requested DIV to bump up and down onscreen. I can't use inline block styling to correct this because that overrides the "display: none" triggered in the JS to hide the DIVs..right? I'm guessing the solution is right in front of me, but I've been messing with the JS and CSS for a while now and can't figure out what I need. Is it possible to change the visibility state of the DIVS with jquery so that i can style them inline and still make them invisible as needed?

Jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/ottomaddox/baV5n/3/

using jQuery 1.9.1 and transit.js (link the fiddle)

Current JS:

```
('.circle img').on('click', function(e) {
            var $this = $(this),
                $id = $this.attr('id'),
                $class = $('.about-' + $id);

            if( $class.is(':visible'))
            {
                    return;
            }
            else 
            {
                    $('.slidetext').children().not( $class ).transition({ x: '-100%', opacity : 0 }, function () { $('.slidetext').children().not( $class ).hide()});
                    $('.about-' + $id).css({ x: '100%' });
                    $('.about-' + $id).show().transition({ x: '0%', opacity: 1.0 }); 
                    return;        
            }
        });
```

Thanks for any and all guidance!

Comment: Yes it is possible using `$(element).css("display","block")` or the value needed for display

Comment: thanks! I'm now able to maintain inline-block styling for the visible elements, but the .hide() effect still restyles hidden elements to display:none, and the div requested by the button click still "jumps" as it slides into view.

Comment: yes it looks like they're stacked vertically and when slide is finished it pops up as if there was a transition in Y axis, have you tried to style the divs horizontally using `float`? not sure if that way transitions would work either

Comment: another thing that is happening is that the divs being hidden after slide are literally getting hid after the transition, generally in a slider you would want it to behave like a "viewport", you know the hidden divs are there with they're sizes and all, just not visible in the "window"

Comment: i have tried floating the divs, and that wasn't working either, i think because when display is set to "none" by the hide() effect, the element is removed from the HTML entirely. re: the viewport suggestion, i will experiment with alternate methods of hiding/locating the divs and see if that clears up the issue. thanks very much for your help!

Comment: what about changing instead of `hide` to something like this `this.css('visibility', 'hidden');`

Comment: i tried that as well, thanks!--but transit.js doesn't seem to play nice with the visibility style... i did actually figure out a working solution, but my rep's too low to post it... had to give the hidden divs absolute position and the wrapper a min-height.. i lost vertical centering but otherwise it looks quite polished now.. will post my solution after the requisite number of noob-proof hours pass!

Answer (score 0):

Got it (more or less)!

Had to give all the divs in the transit.js sequence an absolute position and fixed height relative to the "slidetext" container (which has a relative position). I do lose vertical centering, but that's easier to work around than the glitchy animations.

Also tweaked the script so that only visible divs are animated from slide to slide (not sure it makes a difference, but seems tidier).

For anybody else's reference:

Updated JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ottomaddox/baV5n/3/

```
<script>
            $('.circle img').on('click', function(e) {
                var $this = $(this),
                    $id = $this.attr('id'),
                    $class = $('.about-' + $id);

                if( $class.is(':visible'))
                {
                        return;
                }
                else 
                {
                        $('.slidetext').children(':visible').not( $class ).transition({ x: '-100%', opacity : 0 }, function () { $('.slidetext').children(':visible').not( $class ).hide()});
                        $('.about-' + $id).css({ x: '100%', display: 'inline-block' });
                        $('.about-' + $id).show().transition({ x: '0%', opacity: 1.0 }); 
                        return;        
                }
            });
</script>
```

Relevant CSS:

```
.slidetext {
position:relative;
min-height:350px;
}

.intro, .about-chef, .about-cater, .about-workshop {
width:100%;
height:100%;
position:absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
display:inline;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

In order for this to work, button images should have ids corresponding to 'about-' divs, and all divs but the introductory text must be hidden on load.

Hope this makes some sense. Thanks again G. Mendes for pointing me in the right direction.